# How can I add folder to outlook without permission to root folder

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I am trying to add shared folder to MS Outlook 2010. When I do this with 
file=>open=>open use's folder there is no issue. The folder appears but it is very uncomfortable to use mailbox like that. The main issue is that when I added additional mailbox I cannot access it. I get message

> Cannot display the folder. Microsoft Outlook cannot access the specified folder location. The operation failed. An object cannot be found.

I think that I have not permission to the root folder of mailbox and this is why I cannot get to the folder(which is actually mailbox). unfortunately I cannot check if I have the permission.
**Is there any way to add the folder permanently?**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be an owner with Full Mailbox access to add that Mailbox to an existing or new Outlook profile (this is the most "permanent" way). Otherwise the owner of that Mailbox will need to use the Delegate options to share one or more of their default Outlook folders with you (sharing other non-default folders aren't possible). Once you access a shared folder it should be added to the Navigation module for that folder type so you can access it quickly later.

If the owner doesn't share as Full Mailbox or via Delegates, then you don't have access to any folders and cannot view them.